# Runningfunctional tests in interactive mode using TFS 2017 with team project source control

Tags: tfs, functional-testing

We are trying to run our functional tests in interactive mode using TFS 2017 with team project source control.
We got this running in other team projects where GIT is used.
We deploy the test agent with the option for updating it activated
We have also tried to reuse the test agent machines from the GIT team project where it works, to no avail.

The DTAExecutionHost.exe.txt gives

I, 8816, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:38.397, 44435081265562, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Main.TryReadAndCacheVssCredentials Acquiring the Token Info
I, 8816, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:38.485, 44435082478968, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Communicating to the Token Service http://myTfsUrl:8080/tfs/myCollection
W, 8816, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:39.528, 44435097416029, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Service task failed. Retry attempt 10.
I, 20572, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:42.835, 44435144796158, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Main.TryReadAndCacheVssCredentials Acquiring the Token Info
I, 20572, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:42.928, 44435146081842, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Communicating to the Token Service http://myTfsUrl:8080/tfs/myCollection
I, 20572, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:44.749, 44435172160608, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Closing the Token Service
I, 20572, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:46.151, myTestMachine\DTAExecutionHost, ExecutionTaskStateModel.GetExecutionAdapter : Initializing VstestAdapter.
I, 20572, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:46.152, myTestMachine\DTAExecutionHost, ExecutionTaskStateModel.Start : Starting to monitor tasks
V, 20572, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:46.157, myTestMachine\DTAExecutionHost, TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener.DispatchAsync : Getting Command for Test Agent Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Test.WebApi.TestAgent
Web method running: [http://myTfsUrl:8080/tfs/myCollection/_apis/test/Agents/74959/Commands/0] (GET)0[test]
I, 20572, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:46.214, 44435193134421, DTAExecutionHost.exe, ********************************************************************
I, 20572, 1, 2017/07/18, 12:33:46.214, 44435193135389, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Main.InitializeAndStartExecutionHost. ExecutionHost has been started
Web method response: [http://myTfsUrl:8080/tfs/myCollection/_apis/test/Agents/74959/Commands/0] (GET)0[test] 57 ms
V, 20572, 7, 2017/07/18, 12:33:46.606, myTestMachine\DTAExecutionHost, TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener:DispatchAsync
W, 20572, 7, 2017/07/18, 12:33:46.609, myTestMachine\DTAExecutionHost, TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener.DispatchAsync : TestExecutionCommand received with None. Retrying it.
W, 20572, 7, 2017/07/18, 12:33:46.610, myTestMachine\DTAExecutionHost, TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener.DispatchAsync : Queue not found. Delaying for 3000 milliseconds.
V, 20572, 4, 2017/07/18, 12:33:49.620, myTestMachine\DTAExecutionHost, TestExecutionServiceCommandQueueListener.DispatchAsync : Getting Command for Test Agent Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Test.WebApi.TestAgent

Calling the API at http://myTfsUrl:8080/tfs/myCollection/_apis/test/Agents/74959
gives the result {"id":74957,"name":"myTestMachine","dtlEnvironment":{"id":0,"url":"dta://env/myProject/_apis/82470/201707181206420966"},"dtlMachine":{"id":0,"name":"myTestMachine:5985"},"capabilities":[],"testRunId":-1}
I assume the error is caused by testRunId":-1 as test executions from the GIT projects have a positive testRunId.
Any idea why?

Comment: Can you share the entire logs here?

Comment: Do you mean the DTAExecutionHost.exe log?

Comment: The build logs and DTAExection logs.

Comment: I would be more confident sharing them via a MS mail account. Could you provide one?

Comment: Thanks, I sent you the logs. When this will be sorted out I'll update this post so it will be of use to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was due to the team project having been migrated manually to another instance of tfs, and a few fields were missing.